# Virtualenv shell errors

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I've just installed virtualenv (with Python 2.7.2) on my Mac, and I followed the guide here: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

But I now get the following errors when I start up my shell every time:

```
stevedore.extension Could not load 'user_scripts': distribute
stevedore.extension distribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 62, in __init__
    invoke_kwds,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 74, in _load_one_plugin
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1953, in load
    if require: self.require(env, installer)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1966, in require
    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: distribute
stevedore.extension Could not load 'project': distribute
stevedore.extension distribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 62, in __init__
    invoke_kwds,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 74, in _load_one_plugin
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1953, in load
    if require: self.require(env, installer)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1966, in require
    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: distribute
stevedore.extension Could not load 'user_scripts': distribute
stevedore.extension distribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 62, in __init__
    invoke_kwds,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 74, in _load_one_plugin
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1953, in load
    if require: self.require(env, installer)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1966, in require
    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: distribute
```

I don't know if it is affecting this problem, but I am using ZSH.

I tried to install stevedore through pip (sudo pip install stevedore), but I get the following error:

```
sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
removing '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
setuptools 0.6c11 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
TXSLs-MacBook-Pro% sudo pip install stevedore --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: stevedore in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking distribute (from stevedore)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute

Installing collected packages: distribute
  Running setup.py install for distribute
    Before install bootstrap.
    Scanning installed packages
    Setuptools installation detected at /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
    Egg installation
    Patching...
    Renaming /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.OLD.1348764450.4
    Patched done.
    Relaunching...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'install' is not defined
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FAPgYH-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    Before install bootstrap.

Scanning installed packages

Setuptools installation detected at /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg

Egg installation

Patching...

Renaming /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.OLD.1348764450.4

Patched done.

Relaunching...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'install' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FAPgYH-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/distribute
Storing complete log in /Users/txsl/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I manually installed setuptools as I couldn't install anything through pip without it.

What has gone wrong here and how can i fix it? The internet doesn't seem to have many cases of  the error with stevedore. I feel rather stuck at the moment!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting, it looks like you are having the following error: [install glitch when using pip + virtualenv](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/91/install-glitch-when-using-pip-virtualenv).

The issue is created when using the -distribute switch.  The fix is (without re-running virtualenv with --distribute):

```
source bin/activate
wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py
```

Comment: I get stuck at the first line! :
`source bin/activate
source: no such file or directory: bin/activate`

Comment: To execute that line you need to make sure that you have changed directories into wherever you created your virtualenv.  So if you created a virtualenv called vetest in your user profile you would need to type the following before executing that command:
cd ~/vetest

then you would type...

source bin/activate

Comment: Wait so do I need to do this for every virtualenv i create? I haven't actually set any up yet.

Comment: Well the answer is two fold.  You could uninstall and reinstall without the --distribute option.  Or you have to do this every time.

Comment: Cool. Sorry to be useless, but would you mind taking me through uninstalling it? I'm not very confident with this!
I would much rather reinstall than have to do that every time!!

Comment: I am going to assume you used pip.  To uninstall virtualenv on the command line use the following command:  sudo pip uninstall virtualenv

Comment: I've just realised that I definitely didn't install it with the --distribute option (or if I did, I didn't know what I did), and all I did was `sudo install virtualenv`So what went wrong and how would I be able to fix it? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: At this point I would start over.  Back everything out, and follow these directions through step 4.  http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/

Comment: I found the best way was to use pythonbrew and virtualenv burrito. To be honest, I couldn't figure out any other way to do it other than using pythonbrew and burrito. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3179227) and brainsik's comment

Comment: python-distribute.org no longer exists, but the downloaded script is still available: http://web.archive.org/web/20130402211704/http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py . These days, you're better off using setuptools since distribute has been merged back in.

Comment: since you're on mac and using homebrew, just `pip install distribute`. No need to activate anything first since the problem is a the global/system level.

Comment: This answer needs to be updated. python-distribute.org is now a malware site.

Answer (score 20):

I also use zsh and had a similar problem. I solved with this:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

I have the package `python-pip` installed in my Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Yup, that worked! In my case, I use homebrew to upgrade python 2.7.3 to python 2.7.5. The previous virtual environment that was created in python 2.7.3 will have this same problem. The key is to deactivate that virtual environment and then upgrade virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper for the system-wide python, which is exactly what Marcos suggested above. Works like a charm! I used: sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

Comment: `pip install --upgrade virtualenv virtualenvwrapper` (note the --upgrade) worked for me after upgrading to Mavericks and then upgrading Python via Homebrew.

Comment: this worked for me in after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7):

Had the same error message, upgrading the setuptools resolved the issue for me.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

I've found the information in this thread: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.virtualenv/month=20131001

Comment: Worked for me. I did sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools, then sudo uninstall virtualenv and sudo uninstall virtualenvwrapper, then reinstalled them with sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper. Worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after upgrading to OSX Mavericks. I fixed it by installing distribute globally.

```
sudo pip install distribute
```

I deactivated my current virtualenv first.

Comment: This also fixed it for me on Mavericks.